# Xpages setvalue bug?

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-ssjs

[image: BUG]

My database allow Anonymous to access the database and submit form to do process
It have 3 roles inside [Applicant],[Admin],[Reviewer]

**problem:**

I need to update "Email" field by combining 3 different "mail" field to combine it. So i use add element but it seem save wrong data, it give an extra [applicant]. Attached image will display how it display

```
var v;
//  Update mail 1 and mail 2 and mail3 into Email field!
if  
(
    (document1.getValue("Mail1")!=null && document1.getValue("Mail1")!="")&&
    (document1.getValue("Mail2")!=null && document1.getValue("Mail2")!="")&&
    (document1.getValue("Mail3")!=null && document1.getValue("Mail3")!="")
)   //all not empty
    {
        v.addElement(document1.getValue("Mail1")+"@brookedockyard.com.my"); 
        v.addElement(document1.getValue("Mail2")+"@brookedockyard.com.my");
        v.addElement(document1.getValue("Mail3")+"@brookedockyard.com.my"); 
        document1.replaceItemValue("Email",v)


else if
(
    (document1.getValue("Mail1")!=null && document1.getValue("Mail1")!="")&&
    (document1.getValue("Mail2")==null && document1.getValue("Mail2")=="")&&
    (document1.getValue("Mail3")===null && document1.getValue("Mail3")=="")
)   //  only have mail 1
    {
        document1.replaceItemValue("Email", document1.getValue("Mail1")+"@brookedockyard.com.my")
    }
else if
(
    (document1.getValue("Mail1")!=null && document1.getValue("Mail1")!="")&&
    (document1.getValue("Mail2")!=null && document1.getValue("Mail2")!="")&&
    (document1.getValue("Mail3")==null && document1.getValue("Mail3")=="")
)   //  only have mail 1 and mail 2
    {
        v.addElement(document1.getValue("Mail1")+"@brookedockyard.com.my"); 
        v.addElement(document1.getValue("Mail2")+"@brookedockyard.com.my"); 
        document1.replaceItemValue("Email",v)


else if
(   
    (document1.getValue("Mail1")!=null && document1.getValue("Mail1")!="")&&
    (document1.getValue("Mail2")==null && document1.getValue("Mail2")=="")&&
    (document1.getValue("Mail3")!=null && document1.getValue("Mail3")!="")
)       //  only have mail 1 and mail 3
    {
        v.addElement(document1.getValue("Mail1")+"@brookedockyard.com.my"); 
        v.addElement(document1.getValue("Mail3")+"@brookedockyard.com.my"); 
        document1.replaceItemValue("Email",v)

    }
```

i am using serverside javascript to save document. But during save it add extra information inside the system.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? How you call it on the XPage, where you initialize v, etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code needs some optimization. This code does the same as yours:

```
var v = [];
["Mail1", "Mail2", "Mail3"].forEach(function(name) {
    if (document1.getValue(name)) {
        v.push(document1.getValue(name)+"@brookedockyard.com.my"); 
    }
});
document1.replaceItemValue("Email",v);
```

In addition it initializes the variable `v`as an empty array. Use arrays instead of Vectors when possible. It's more JavaScript native.

Answer (score 3):

Where is your Vector (`v`) created? You're just adding elements to that existing Vector, so your code (Form setting if using computeWithForm, XPage setting, SSJS code) must be initialising that Vector with an "[Applicant]" value or retrieving a Vector that already includes the "[Applicant]" value.

The chances of IBM code adding "[Applicant]" to the Item during the `setValue()` method are nil. The bug is almost certainly in your application code, not introduced by `setValue()`. Eclipse search should help identify where application code is setting that value.

Comment: i declare v as a variable  [var v] then with code only....it like go get my roles to update it~

Comment: i already use that variable some place~ that y save extra value inside! thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Create a request scoped bean.

**faces-config.xml**

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>forgetSsjs</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>demo.bean.ForgetSsjsBean
    </managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

**the bean**

```
package demo.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.faces.FacesException;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import lotus.domino.NotesException;

import com.ibm.commons.util.StringUtil;
import com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument;
import com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil;

public class ForgetSsjsBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void saveTheDoc() {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        DominoDocument wrapper = (DominoDocument) FacesUtil.resolveVariable(facesContext,
                "document1");

        Set<String> emails = new HashSet<String>();

        try {           
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                addEmail(wrapper.getItemValueString("Mail" + i), emails);
            }

            if (!emails.isEmpty()) {
                wrapper.replaceItemValue("Email", new Vector<String>(emails));
                wrapper.save();
            }
        } catch (NotesException e) {
            throw new FacesException(e);
        }
    }

    private void addEmail(String name, Set<String> emails) {
        if (StringUtil.isEmpty(name)) {
            return;
        }

        emails.add(name + "@brookedockyard.com.my");
    }

}
```

Link your event handler action to the method you destine for saving the document:

**the xsp page**

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" ... />
</xp:this.data>

...

<xp:button id="button1" value="save this thing">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" action="#{forgetSsjs.saveTheDoc}" />
</xp:button>
```